# Updating/deleting calendar event without knowing owner

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Is there a way, using the Graph API, to update/delete a calendar event without knowing who the event owner is? I see the api call to do these operations by including the owner of the meeting in the url path, but in my situation, another user may need to update/delete an event after the fact using the api, so we wouldn't know at that point who created it, unless I saved off the event owner for every event on my side. I am saving the event id on our side, but I don't know if I also need to save the user who created the event along with the id, in order to later update/delete the event. I am using application level access for the Graph API.

Or is there a way to look up the event owner, given the event id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to know both the `id` and the "location" in order to delete an `event`. I say "location" because there are several places an `event` could potentially exist.

If the event lives within a user's default calendar you would need to know the `userPrincipalName` and the event `id`:

```
DELETE /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/events/{id}
```

If the event lives within a user's non-default calendar, you would need to know the `userPrinipcalName`, the calendar `id` and the event `id`:

```
DELETE /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/calendars/{id}/events/{id}
```

If the event lives within a group or team's calendar, you would need to know the group `id` and the event `id`:

```
DELETE /groups/{id}/events/{id}
```

One important thing to keep in mind is an event's `id` *can* change. You should also make sure you store the `iCalUId`. This is a persistent identifier that is you can use to validate you have the correct event or filter the `/events` list to find should the `id` you expect be missing.

Comment: Thanks for the info.